# sscanf not parsing int with STM32

Tags: c, embedded, stm32

Why does the following code works on the PC but not on a STM32?

the code:

```
n = sscanf(args[0].s, "%*3[ATD]%*1[*]%*d%*3[*]%d%*1[#]%1[\r]", &cid, &cr);
```

The string to be parsed:

```
ATD*99***9#\r\n
```

On the PC the code correctly returns n=2, cid=9 and cr=\r. On STM32 I get n=2, **cid=0** and cr=\r.
Does anyone have any clue?

Comment: Suppose you try the more straight-forward `n = sscanf(str, "ATD*%*d***%d#%1[\r]", &cid, &cr);` Or are there not a fixed number of stars? Why did you need to restrict the string lengths, when there is no storage?

Comment: Note that `%*3[ATD]` matches DDD, AAA, TTT, and so on, as well as ATD.

Comment: Aside: the `&cr` is possibly incorrect for a string target, and the `%1[\r]` incorrect for a `char` target. Show a complete example including variable definitions, and the output statement.

Comment: What are the types of `cid` and `cr`?  If you do not have `char cr[2];` (or a longer array), then you could be getting the null byte overwriting `cid` and accidentally zeroing its value.  On your PC, there may be more space between `cid` and `cr` than on the STM32, or the variables may simply be laid out differently so the buffer overflow doesn't affect the PC version.  Assuming `cr` is an array, the `&` before it in the call to `sscanf()` is incorrect — it passes a `char (*)[2]` where a `char *` is expected.

Comment: @WeatherVane: I'm not convinced your 'aside' is an aside.  I suspect that it is part of the cause of the trouble.  Judging from the information that "`cr=\r`", the `cr` variable is likely defined as `char cr;`, but that is not a good idea as it leads to writing outside the bounds of the variable.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler because of that, my little test program caused me to write an initial erroneous comment that I had to delete, and then I forgot about it, blaming myself.

Comment: IMO once a `scanf`-type format string becomes too complex, it's time to find a cleaner way to solve the problem.

Comment: @WeatherVane cid is a int type and cr is a char (single char, not array).

Comment: So there you have it. The `char cr[]` **array** target required by `%[]` needs at least 2 elements, to make it a nul terminated string. The resulting buffer overflow causes undefined behaviour, with a different result on different systems.